# how to use the laravel subdomain routing function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using the following code its from the laravel 4 site

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'), function() {

    Route::get('user/{id}', function($account, $id) {
        // ...
     return Redirect::to('https://www.myapp.com'.'/'.$account);
    });

});
```

the idea is to redirect subdomain.myapp.com to myapp.com/user/subdomain
.what I have is not working any suggestions?sorry I just started with laravel about a month now.

Comment: What is the url you are trying? i'm guessing you should remove the `user/{id}` and replace it with `/` and then go to https://fogsy.myapp.com

Comment: sometimes I can be so dumb... thanks @MarcvdM

Comment: Do you solve this @cppit ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove `user/{id}` and replace it with `/` and then use the following url `https://accountname.myapp.com` and it will redirect to `https://www.myapp.com/accountname`

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'), function() {

    Route::get('/', function($account, $id) {
        // ...
        return Redirect::to('https://www.myapp.com'.'/'.$account);
    });

});
```

Edit the answer to the correct answer

Comment: sorry this is not the answer, the subdomain is not in used if you redirect it directly

Comment: I want to use it to redirect from ```www.mydomain.com``` to ```mydomain.com```. It is a 301 redirect?

Comment: @Marc vd M https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811979/subdomain-base-without-uri-unable-to-catch-base-url

Answer (score 3):

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'), function() {

    Route::get('/', function($account) {
        // ...
        return Redirect::to('https://www.myapp.com/'.$account);
    });

});
```

as Marc vd M answer but remove $id from get's closure function.

why use `'https://www.myapp.com'.'/'.$account` and not `'https://www.myapp.com/'.$account`