# Laravel subdomain parse

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, routes, subdomain

I want to get subdomains from url in laravel. Using this at now

```
App::before(function($request)
{
        if(Request::path() == '/' && !Request::ajax()){
        $urlParts = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        if($urlParts[0] == 'fasfin' || $urlParts[1] == 'fasfin' && $urlParts[0] == 'www') {Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');} //check if url is main site
        elseif($urlParts[0] == 'www') { $subdomain = $urlParts[1]; return App::make('SubdomainController')->getIndex($subdomain);} //fix for www.subdomain.mydomain.com
        else {$subdomain = $urlParts[0]; return App::make('SubdomainController')->getIndex($subdomain);}
        } //get subdomain
});
```

But this is kind of very bad code, i know. Trick from official docs with {subdomain}.mydomain.com doesn't works. I enabled all subdomains from apache with

```
Server Alias *.mydomain.com
```

## Update

Changed my code to this

```
if(!Request::ajax()){
        $isSubdomain = false;
        $urlParts = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        if($urlParts[0] == 'fasfin' || $urlParts[1] == 'fasfin' && $urlParts[0] == 'www') {Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');}
        elseif($urlParts[0] == 'www') { $subdomain = $urlParts[1]; $isSubdomain = true;}
        else {$subdomain = $urlParts[0]; $isSubdomain = true;}
        if($isSubdomain)
        {
            $user = App::make('SubdomainController')->checkIndex($subdomain);
            if($user instanceof Exception) return View::make('subdomain.notExist');
            $shop = App::make('SubdomainController')->getIndex($subdomain);
            if($shop instanceof Exception) return 'Shop was already registered, but doesn't created yet';
        }
    }
```

#### At now new question is

How to pass variable to view every time?
In the end i have variable $shop and want to pass it into view home.blade.php every time when it called

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326980/how-to-use-the-laravel-subdomain-routing-function

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```
View::share('shop', $shop);
```

Comment: if you wanty it only to besahred with one page like home you can use a composer:
`View::composer('home', function ($view) {` 
`view()->share('shop', $shop);` 
`});`