# Link From Subdomain to Root Domain Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, subdomain

I have 1 subdomain in my app: `admin.test.com` and then the root is `test.com`. While in `admin.test.com` I want to send an email to a user to log in to `test.com/login/aseqgaasd` but right now it is sending the link to `admin.test.com/login/aseqgaasd`.

How can I use the `{{ URL::to('login', array($code)) }}` method to route to the main domain and not the sub domain?

I do **not** want to use .htaccess

Comment: Check this question it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326980/how-to-use-the-laravel-subdomain-routing-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use named routes. For example, in your routes.php:

```
Route::get('login/{param}', array('as' => 'TestLogin', 'uses' => 'HomeController@login'));
```

Then, in your Blade template:

```
{{ URL::route('TestLogin', array('param' => $code)) }}
```

I don't know what your routes file looks like, so you would need to adjust this to fit your needs. The important piece is the `'as' => 'TestLogin'` since that's what names the route and allows it to be referred to as such throughout your application.